# What is ActiveX Hosting?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, activex, windows-ce, flash

I need to get the [Flash Player ActiveX](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer_pocketpc/downloads/player.html) on the .NET Compact Framework in Windows CE 5.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/81045c07-8d60-4be6-95a0-be3b42bdad81/) thread says I need to create an "ActiveX Host" for Net CF in order to accomplish this. How do I do this? Does it mean that I program a COM container component for my ActiveX? (Flash Player)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN article explains it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx) (with Flash as an example even).